# PHP Regex: Stop if exists or carry one

Tags: php, regex

I am struggling to match for a phrase with an if char exists regex query. What I want to be able to do is scan this string:

```
teamplayerID=5432&groupplayerID=2345
```

and only get out `teamplayerID=5432`. Sometimes &groupplayerID exists and sometimes not.

I have tried:

> /teamplayerID=(.*)(&?)/

over at https://regex101.com/r/QmMUkm/1

However that code above seems to select the entire string,

## Question

How do I get the regex to stop if it detects an `&` and only get what I want but also select what I want even if no `&` exists.

Comment: I think you're going to have to post examples of strings that don't work as you expect them to as well.

Comment: Is teamplayer always a number?

Comment: You are trying to solve the wrong problem. Use the PHP function [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and the problem simply vanishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `[^&]*` [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
teamplayerID=([^&]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QmMUkm/2)

The `[^&]*` pattern matches 0 or more occurrences of characters other than `&`.

If the ID is always a group of digits, just use `\d*` (*0+ digits*) instead, [`teamplayerID=(\d*)`](https://regex101.com/r/QmMUkm/3).

Comment: Wow that was fast and a working solution. Cannot accept for 12 mins. :)

Answer (score 0):

If Teamplayer is always a number you can use \d+

`teamplayerID=(\d+)`
https://regex101.com/r/xj1WNN/1

If it's not always a number you can use \w+ which will match both numbers and letters.

`teamplayerID=(\w+)`
https://regex101.com/r/xj1WNN/1

---

There is always a posibility for non regex.

```
$str = "teamplayerID=54";

$pos1 = strpos($str, "=")+1;
$pos2 = strpos($str, "&", $pos1);
if($pos2 == 0) $pos2 = strlen($str);
echo substr($str, $pos1, $pos2-$pos1);
```

Find `=` save as pos1.
Find `&` after `=` and save as pos2.
If there is no `&` use strlen($str) as pos2.
Substring pos1 and lenght (pos2-pos1).

https://3v4l.org/7cj6J

EDIT; Forgot about the groupID not always being there.